# QR Reader for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, qr-code, zxing

So i need to write a QR reader for an iphone application. Usually frameworks like ZXING and ZBAr allow you to download an application and then read the barcode. I want to integrate it within the application itself. So basically i want to be able to tap a button and have it reading the QR code. Is this possible? If so are there any proper documentation on this? I tried using ZXing but when i link binaries libZXingWidget.a is unavailable. Also the documentation is not enough to know how to integrate it within the application. So let me know.

Comment: Are you asking how to add a framework to a project?

Comment: ZXing comes with a GUI-less library last time I checked.

Comment: No. I want to know if there are any frameworks that i can add and use apart from ZXing because i cant find the libZXingWidget.a and also there is no documentation on how i would use it.

Comment: Once you get ZXing set up corectly it is extremely easy to use.  I highly recommend it.  It is also very quick and accurate.  I struggled with it for a couple hours but found some good tutorials on setting it up.  Make sure that you are adding the right "Header Search Paths" and "User Header Search Paths"

Comment: You can always ask here or on the ZXing mailing list if you have problems. The zxing contributors (including myself) watch both pretty carefully. FBOFW, the example projects are the best source of 'how to' information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's code to setup ZBar, make sure to add the SDK to your project and link your library.

-

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
        [ZBarReaderView class];
        readerView.readerDelegate = self;
        readerView.tracksSymbols = NO;

            //CHOOSE CAMERA
            if (some setting isEqual to CameraRear) {
                readerView.device = [self backFacingCameraIfAvailable];
            }
            else {
                readerView.device = [self frontFacingCameraIfAvailable];
            }

        [self relocateReaderPopover:[self interfaceOrientation]];
        [readerView start];
    }

-(AVCaptureDevice *)frontFacingCameraIfAvailable
{
    NSArray *videoDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = nil;
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in videoDevices)
    {
        if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront)
        {
            captureDevice = device;
            break;
        }
    }

    //  couldn't find one on the front, so just get the default video device.
    if ( ! captureDevice)
    {
        captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    }

    return captureDevice;
}

-(AVCaptureDevice *)backFacingCameraIfAvailable
{
    NSArray *videoDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = nil;
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in videoDevices)
    {
        if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack)
        {
            captureDevice = device;
            break;
        }
    }

    //  couldn't find one on the front, so just get the default video device.
    if ( ! captureDevice)
    {
        captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    }

    return captureDevice;
}

-(void)relocateReaderPopover:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        readerView.previewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
    } else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        readerView.previewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
    } else if (toInterfaceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        readerView.previewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
    } else {
        readerView.previewTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[This is a step-by-step tutorial](http://basheerad.blogspot.com/2012/04/integrating-zxing-qr-code-reader-in.html) on how to add an integrated QR code reader to your iphone app. Look at this [example ZXing project](http://zxing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/iphone/) if you need to know how to use it.

Comment: This one is good too: http://yannickloriot.com/2011/04/how-to-install-zxing-in-xcode-4/

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to integrate ZXING into my test project. I have done this a little time ago so I might not remember all the problems that I faced and solved.
Into my workspace folder I have copied ZXing-2.0 folder. Inside I have only left folders: cpp, docs and iphone. To my workspace (containing the test project) I have added ZXingWidget project from the folder ZXing-2.0. This allowed me to add to linking setting libZXingWidget.a.
When I build my test project, XCode detects dependency and builds the widget first and then builds the test project and links it against libZXingWidget.a.

Here's a simple view controller that I have implemented to display inside camera view able to detect QR code.

```
//
//  MyVC.m
//
//

#import "MyVC.h"
#import "QRCodeReader.h"

@interface MyVC () {
    ZXingWidgetController *_widController;
}

@end

@implementation MyVC

@synthesize labelResultString;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    _widController = [[ZXingWidgetController alloc] initWithDelegate:(id<ZXingDelegate>)self showCancel:YES OneDMode:NO];
    QRCodeReader* qrcodeReader = [[QRCodeReader alloc] init];
    NSSet *readers = [[NSSet alloc ] initWithObjects:qrcodeReader,nil];
    //[qrcodeReader release];
    _widController.readers = readers;
    //[readers release];
    //NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    //_widController.soundToPlay = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[mainBundle pathForResource:@"beep-beep" ofType:@"aiff"] isDirectory:NO];
    _widController.overlayView.displayedMessage = @"";
    _widController.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;

    //[self presentModalViewController:_widController animated:NO];
    _widController.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 300);//self.view.frame;
    _widController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    _widController.overlayView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
    _widController.overlayView.cropRect = CGRectMake(20, 20, 260, 260);

    [self.view addSubview:_widController.view];

    //[_widController release];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];

    self.labelResultString = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    self.labelResultString = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [_widController viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [_widController viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [_widController viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [_widController viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

#pragma mark - ZXingDelegateMethods

- (void)zxingController:(ZXingWidgetController*)controller didScanResult:(NSString *)result {
    self.labelResultString.text = result;
}

- (void)zxingControllerDidCancel:(ZXingWidgetController *)controller {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have ZXing set up correctly the code to get a QR reader is literally this easy:

Make sure to import these two guys for QR:

```
#import "ZXingWidgetController.h"
#import "QRCodeReader.h"
```

Then in your controller you will set up the code reader as follows:

```
ZXingWidgetController *widController = [[ZXingWidgetController alloc] initWithDelegate:self showCancel:YES OneDMode:NO];

QRCodeReader *qrcodeReader = [[QRCodeReader alloc] init];

NSSet *readers = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:qrcodeReader,nil];

widController.readers = readers;

[self presentModalViewController:widController animated:YES];
```

You basically set up the controller that handles the code reading (`ZXingWidgetController`) and then give it a set of all the types of code readers you want (here I just used `QRCodeReader`.)  Lastly, you just present it as a modal view controller.

Then you will need to implement the `<ZXingDelegate>` and the following `delegate` functions:

```
- (void)zxingController:(ZXingWidgetController*)controller didScanResult:(NSString *)result
{  
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@",result);  //Simple NSString result.
}

- (void)zxingControllerDidCancel:(ZXingWidgetController*)controller
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Cancelled");
}
```

The hardest part is just setting it up.  I found this tutorial to be the most helpful (Sorry that I am using a link): [How to install ZXing in Xcode 4](http://yannickloriot.com/2011/04/how-to-install-zxing-in-xcode-4/)  The comments are also helpful if you have any problems.